# Ansible - register GET response over loop, multiple same dict's

Tags: jquery, json, ansible

i'm trying to get the a ID value from a registered GET response that has been looped. But because it's looped the register var now includes the same structure multiple times.

The "get_input_id" var is being extracted from a registered GET response that's been done earlier.

I need to match and verify the extractor ID to the title of the extractor defined in the host file. So i can later do a PUT request where i'm obliged to use a input_id and extractor_id

Anyone got any clues for me to get this working ?, i was thinking of converting the dict's to a list and then iterating over them getting the ID's from json -> extractors -> id

```
  - name: "API GET Input Extractors"
    vars:
      get_input_titles: "{{ get_graylog_inputs.json.inputs | selectattr('title', '==', input.title) | map(attribute='title') | first }}"
      get_input_id: "{{ get_graylog_inputs.json.inputs | selectattr('title', '==', input.title) | map(attribute='id') | first }}"
    uri:
      url: http://{{ ansible_host }}:9000/api/system/inputs/{{ get_input_id }}/extractors
      url_username : "{{ system.users.triple_admin.api_token }}"
      url_password: token
      method: GET
      return_content: yes
    register: get_input_extractors
    loop: "{{ inputs }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: input
    when: "input.title in get_input_titles"
    tags:
      - get_input_extractors

  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ get_input_extractors }}"

  - name: debug
    vars:
      get_input_extractor_id: "{{ get_input_extractors.json.extractors | selectattr('title', '==', input.1.title) | map(attribute='id') }}"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ get_input_extractor_id }}"
    loop: "{{ inputs|subelements('extractors') }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: input
```

Below is a cut down version of the registered var "get_input_extractor" ( the first debug task )
**EDIT: a more representative register var output**
This one includes a list object within results that does not have a json attribute

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [{
        "ansible_loop_var": "input",
        "json": {
            "extractors": [{
                "condition_type": "regex",
                "condition_value": "^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$",
                "converter_exceptions": 0,
                "converters": [],
                "creator_user_id": "triple_admin",
                "cursor_strategy": "copy",
                "exceptions": 0,
                "extractor_config": {
                    "grok_pattern": "%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}"
                },
                "id": "a2d14160-f8f9-11eb-8d07-005056991190",
                "metrics": {
                    "condition": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "condition_hits": 0,
                    "condition_misses": 0,
                    "converters": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "execution": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "total": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "order": 0,
                "source_field": "full_message",
                "target_field": "",
                "title": "ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies",
                "type": "grok"
            }],
            "total": 1
        },
        "msg": "OK (1780 bytes)",
        "redirected": false,
        "status": 200,
        "url": "http://192.168.21.82:9000/api/system/inputs/6104170beca15547502665d6/extractors",
        "x_graylog_node_id": "ba52ad48-0b13-419d-b957-d47d8911b413",
        "x_runtime_microseconds": "2296"
    }, {
        "ansible_loop_var": "input",
        "json": {
            "extractors": [{
                "condition_type": "regex",
                "condition_value": "^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$",
                "converter_exceptions": 0,
                "converters": [],
                "creator_user_id": "triple_admin",
                "cursor_strategy": "copy",
                "exceptions": 0,
                "extractor_config": {
                    "grok_pattern": "%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}"
                },
                "id": "bdd27c20-f8fb-11eb-8d07-005056991190",
                "metrics": {
                    "condition": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "condition_hits": 0,
                    "condition_misses": 0,
                    "converters": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "execution": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "total": {
                        "duration_unit": "microseconds",
                        "rate": {
                            "fifteen_minute": 0,
                            "five_minute": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "one_minute": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "rate_unit": "events/second",
                        "time": {
                            "95th_percentile": 0,
                            "98th_percentile": 0,
                            "99th_percentile": 0,
                            "max": 0,
                            "mean": 0,
                            "min": 0,
                            "std_dev": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "order": 0,
                "source_field": "full_message",
                "target_field": "",
                "title": "ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies",
                "type": "grok"
            }],
            "total": 1
        },
        "msg": "OK (1780 bytes)",
        "redirected": false,
        "status": 200,
        "url": "http://192.168.21.82:9000/api/system/inputs/6104190eeca1554750266814/extractors",
        "x_graylog_node_id": "ba52ad48-0b13-419d-b957-d47d8911b413",
        "x_runtime_microseconds": "2251"
    }, {
        "ansible_loop_var": "input",
        "changed": false,
        "input": {
            "configuration": {
                "allow_override_date": false,
                "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
                "expand_structured_data": false,
                "force_rdns": false,
                "number_worker_threads": 8,
                "override_source": null,
                "port": 5996,
                "recv_buffer_size": null,
                "store_full_message": true
            },
            "extractors": [{
                "condition_type": "regex",
                "condition_value": "^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$",
                "converters": {},
                "cut_or_copy": "copy",
                "extractor_config": {
                    "pattern": "%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}",
                    "type": "grok_pattern"
                },
                "extractor_type": "grok",
                "order": 0,
                "source_field": "full_message",
                "target_field": "",
                "title": "ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies"
            }],
            "global": false,
            "running": true,
            "title": "ansible test input",
            "type": "org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput"
        },
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }]
}
```

Below is the output of the second debug task where i'm trying to pull the "ID" value from each input extractor.

```
ok: [graylog1.tc2.triple-it.nl] => (item=[{'title': 'test_input_api', 'running': True, 'type': 'org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput', 'global': False, 'configuration': {'allow_override_date': False, 'bind_address': '0.0.0.0', 'expand_structured_data': False, 'force_rdns': False, 'number_worker_threads': 8, 'override_source': None, 'port': 5999, 'recv_buffer_size': None, 'store_full_message': True}, 'extractors': [{'title': 'ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]}, {'title': 'ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]) => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7fcf25a8aa98>"
}
ok: [graylog1.tc2.triple-it.nl] => (item=[{'title': 'test_input_api_2', 'running': True, 'type': 'org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput', 'global': False, 'configuration': {'allow_override_date': False, 'bind_address': '0.0.0.0', 'expand_structured_data': False, 'force_rdns': False, 'number_worker_threads': 8, 'override_source': None, 'port': 5995, 'recv_buffer_size': None, 'store_full_message': True}, 'extractors': [{'title': 'ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]}, {'title': 'ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]) => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7fcf25a8aba0>"
}
ok: [graylog1.tc2.triple-it.nl] => (item=[{'title': 'ansible test input', 'running': True, 'type': 'org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput', 'global': False, 'configuration': {'allow_override_date': False, 'bind_address': '0.0.0.0', 'expand_structured_data': False, 'force_rdns': False, 'number_worker_threads': 8, 'override_source': None, 'port': 5996, 'recv_buffer_size': None, 'store_full_message': True}, 'extractors': [{'title': 'ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]}, {'title': 'ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]) => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7fcf25a8ad00>"
}
```

**EDIT:** a second try at extracting and correlating the id value to the title variable defined in the host_vars (think this is a good way of doing it!).

```
  - name: Get all ids in uri results
    vars:
      get_input_extractor_title: "{{ get_input_extractors.results | map(attribute='json.extractors') | flatten | selectattr('title', '==', input.1.title) | map(attribute='title') | list }}"
      get_input_extractor_id: "{{ get_input_extractors.results | map(attribute='json.extractors') | flatten | selectattr('title', '==', input.1.title) | map(attribute='id') | list }}"
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ get_input_extractor_id }}"
    loop: "{{ inputs|subelements('extractors') }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: input
```

Below is the output of the play registering every unique id number.

```
TASK [graylog/extractors : Get all ids in uri results] ******************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 10 August 2021  15:26:49 +0200 (0:00:00.290)       0:00:07.225 ********
ok: [graylog1.tc2.triple-it.nl] => (item=[{'title': 'test_input_api', 'running': True, 'type': 'org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput', 'global': False, 'configuration': {'allow_override_date': False, 'bind_address': '0.0.0.0', 'expand_structured_data': False, 'force_rdns': False, 'number_worker_threads': 8, 'override_source': None, 'port': 5999, 'recv_buffer_size': None, 'store_full_message': True}, 'extractors': [{'title': 'test_input_api TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}, {'title': 'test_input_api BLABLA 2', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]}, {'title': 'test_input_api TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "6b09eeb0-f9d7-11eb-8d07-005056991190"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [graylog1.tc2.triple-it.nl] => (item=[{'title': 'test_input_api', 'running': True, 'type': 'org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput', 'global': False, 'configuration': {'allow_override_date': False, 'bind_address': '0.0.0.0', 'expand_structured_data': False, 'force_rdns': False, 'number_worker_threads': 8, 'override_source': None, 'port': 5999, 'recv_buffer_size': None, 'store_full_message': True}, 'extractors': [{'title': 'test_input_api TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}, {'title': 'test_input_api BLABLA 2', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]}, {'title': 'test_input_api BLABLA 2', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]) => {
    "msg": [
        []
    ]
}
ok: [graylog1.tc2.triple-it.nl] => (item=[{'title': 'test_input_api_2', 'running': True, 'type': 'org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput', 'global': False, 'configuration': {'allow_override_date': False, 'bind_address': '0.0.0.0', 'expand_structured_data': False, 'force_rdns': False, 'number_worker_threads': 8, 'override_source': None, 'port': 5995, 'recv_buffer_size': None, 'store_full_message': True}, 'extractors': [{'title': 'test_input_api_2 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]}, {'title': 'test_input_api_2 TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "6b9edbb0-f9d7-11eb-8d07-005056991190"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [graylog1.tc2.triple-it.nl] => (item=[{'title': 'ansible test input', 'running': True, 'type': 'org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput', 'global': False, 'configuration': {'allow_override_date': False, 'bind_address': '0.0.0.0', 'expand_structured_data': False, 'force_rdns': False, 'number_worker_threads': 8, 'override_source': None, 'port': 5996, 'recv_buffer_size': None, 'store_full_message': True}, 'extractors': [{'title': 'ansible test input TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]}, {'title': 'ansible test input TCP/UDP Denies', 'cut_or_copy': 'copy', 'source_field': 'full_message', 'target_field': '', 'extractor_type': 'grok', 'extractor_config': {'type': 'grok_pattern', 'pattern': '%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}'}, 'converters': {}, 'condition_type': 'regex', 'condition_value': '^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$', 'order': 0}]) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "6c3464f0-f9d7-11eb-8d07-005056991190"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, since you looped, your register contains a `results` attribute which is a list of all individual results. You can use them as "normal" (i.e. unlooped) results if you loop on "{{ your_registered_var.results }}". For more info on the subject see [Referencing variables with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop).

Next, the service you request is returning a correct json content with a `Content-type: application/json` meaning that the [`uri` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) is returning in each result a `json` key containing the already decoded json string you can use as an object.

From your above question I understood (I have a doubt about that so please edit your question to be more specific if this is not the case) that your requirement is to get a list of all the `id`s attributes in each extractor in the `extractors` lists. For this you basically need to

- create a list of all `json.extractors` attributes in your `results` list.
- flatten that list so all `extractors` elements in all `json` objects are in a single level list.
- extract only the `id` field in all remaining elements in the list.

You don't need any fancy `json_query` requests for this nor even a loop as demonstrated in the following playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your orig data as a single json line for legibility
    get_input_extractors: {"changed": false, "msg": "All items completed", "results": [{"ansible_loop_var": "input", "json": {"extractors": [{"condition_type": "regex", "condition_value": "^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$", "converter_exceptions": 0, "converters": [], "creator_user_id": "triple_admin", "cursor_strategy": "copy", "exceptions": 0, "extractor_config": {"grok_pattern": "%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}"}, "id": "a2d14160-f8f9-11eb-8d07-005056991190", "metrics": {"condition": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}, "condition_hits": 0, "condition_misses": 0, "converters": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}, "execution": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}, "total": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}}, "order": 0, "source_field": "full_message", "target_field": "", "title": "ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies", "type": "grok"}], "total": 1}, "msg": "OK (1780 bytes)", "redirected": false, "status": 200, "url": "http://192.168.21.82:9000/api/system/inputs/6104170beca15547502665d6/extractors", "x_graylog_node_id": "ba52ad48-0b13-419d-b957-d47d8911b413", "x_runtime_microseconds": "2301"}, {"ansible_loop_var": "input", "json": {"extractors": [{"condition_type": "regex", "condition_value": "^.*(ASA-\\d-106023).*$", "converter_exceptions": 0, "converters": [], "creator_user_id": "triple_admin", "cursor_strategy": "copy", "exceptions": 0, "extractor_config": {"grok_pattern": "%{CISCOTAG:logid}: %{CISCO_ACTION:action} %{WORD:proto} src %{NOTSPACE:srcint}:%{IPV4:srcip}/%{BASE10NUM:srcport} dst %{NOTSPACE:dstint}:%{IPV4:dstip}/%{BASE10NUM:dstport} by access-group %{QUOTEDSTRING:acl}"}, "id": "bdd27c20-f8fb-11eb-8d07-005056991190", "metrics": {"condition": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}, "condition_hits": 0, "condition_misses": 0, "converters": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}, "execution": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}, "total": {"duration_unit": "microseconds", "rate": {"fifteen_minute": 0, "five_minute": 0, "mean": 0, "one_minute": 0, "total": 0}, "rate_unit": "events/second", "time": {"95th_percentile": 0, "98th_percentile": 0, "99th_percentile": 0, "max": 0, "mean": 0, "min": 0, "std_dev": 0}}}, "order": 0, "source_field": "full_message", "target_field": "", "title": "ASA106023 TCP/UDP Denies", "type": "grok"}], "total": 1}, "msg": "OK (1780 bytes)", "redirected": false, "status": 200, "url": "http://192.168.21.82:9000/api/system/inputs/6104190eeca1554750266814/extractors", "x_graylog_node_id": "ba52ad48-0b13-419d-b957-d47d8911b413", "x_runtime_microseconds": "2263"}]}

  tasks:
    - name: Get all ids in uri results
      debug:
        msg: "{{ get_input_extractors.results | map(attribute='json.extractors') 
          | flatten | map(attribute='id') }}"
        # Note: if running ansible < 2.10 your will need to
        # explicitely turn the result into a list
        # msg: "{{ get_input_extractors.results | map(attribute='json.extractors') 
        #   | flatten | map(attribute='id') | list }}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook bla.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Get all ids in uri results] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "a2d14160-f8f9-11eb-8d07-005056991190",
        "bdd27c20-f8fb-11eb-8d07-005056991190"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: When i copy you're proposed solution 1on1 as a test i get the following result:

`ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f6f3e416ba0>"`

When i apply it on my playbook i get an error i really don't get because the dict definitely contains results.json.extractors.

`FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'json'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/d.denouden/ansible/roles/graylog/extractors/tasks/get_extractors.yml':`

Comment: I've fixed the issue where i would get the `generator object do_map at 0x7f6f3e416ba0 ` message in you're example by giving the debug msg a `| list` at the end. 

I'm still not sure why i can't run the exact same thing on the registered var directly, still getting the message that there is no attribute json within the dict.

Comment: `list` filter is mandatory for ansible < 2.10. I updated my answer with a specific note.

Comment: yeah i'm running 2.9.12. I found the issue with my playbook. Within the `registered_var->results` there is also a list object that does not have a json attribute. I've updated my registered_var output in the question to include this piece. So i need to be able to get the id's from where they are available.

Comment: What have you tried to fix that new issue ? I don't see any tries / new output / errors from a tentative to fix your problem in your edit. If you don't know where to start for this last one, see the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) in which you can check with the [`defined` test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.defined).

Comment: I think i've got it, updated the question !

Answer (score 0):

Is this is the query you're looking for?

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        get_input_extractor_id: "{{ get_input_extractors.results|
                                    json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: '[].json.extractors[].id'
```